# Can I try latest Nautilus (3.5.4 now) in Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, lubuntu

http://www.iloveubuntu.net/redesigned-nautilus-landed-ubuntu-1210

Is it only for Quantal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the source files from [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/nautilus/1:3.5.4-0ubuntu1) and compile it yourself.

Nautilus 3.5.4 requires gtk+3.5.5 but Ubuntu 12.04 still has 3.4.2, so you might have to wait a bit to try it, until 3.5.5 rolls out.

As you might know, nautilus 3.5.4 is not much different from the current version, so you're not missing much.

Comment: I can download it no problem, as for compiling it myself, if I knew to do that I would not be here posting naive questions on AskUbuntu! ;)

Comment: I'll post the instructions on compiling.

Comment: will you put instructions on compiling?

Comment: I tried, but couldn't compile. It requires certain packages which have not yet landed on 12.04, and doesn't seem to be any way to download them. You should probably make a live USB of 12.10 beta 1, and use that to try nautilus.